What kind of apps can I design for case studies to get my first internship job?
I'm currently looking for my first UI/UX design Internship role in a Company like Google, Airbnb, or Amazon. so I want to do a case study. However, I'm confused about what categories of apps I can design. for example: Productivity app, Education, E-commerce, etc.
anyone, please suggest me. Thank you in advance.

Instead of designing a new app, maybe focus on improving a functionality of already existing app. Nobody needs another "Evernote" or "Google maps" like apps, but improving something within such apps can really shows your problem solving skills which a lot of companies are actually looking for.
Find an app you like, check the reviews and find out if there are some UX issues users are complaining about. Then take this issues and try to solve it.

x2 Ratoncito_Perez comment. You can take an application that you use often and find a flaw in the process then create a use case how you might solve it.
